# How to extract image inside bounding box which was drawn manually

Tags: python, opencv

I have many images which have bounding boxes all drawn in the same color and are all rectangles.
How can I extract the image inside the bounding box?
There are similar questions but none of those solutions work properly.
Can anybody help please?
The below image is an example.
I would like to use python Opencv to do this.

[image: Image with rectangle regions to extract]

**EDIT------------------------------------------------------------------**

This code works perfectly for all the images. It's based on answer from sipho

```
img = cv2.imread(img_url)
hsv_min = np.array([0, 250, 100],np.uint8)
hsv_max = np.array([10, 255, 255],np.uint8)

hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

frame_threshed = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, hsv_min, hsv_max)

# Perform morphology
se = np.ones((1,1), dtype='uint8')
image_close = cv2.morphologyEx(frame_threshed, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, se)
cv2.imshow(image_close)
cv2.waitkey(0)    

# detect contours on the morphed image
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(image_close,127,255,0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

areaArray = []
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    areaArray.append(area)

# Sort countours based on area
sorteddata = sorted(zip(areaArray, contours), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)

# find the nth largest contour [n-1][1], in this case 2
largestcontour = sorteddata[0][1]

# get the bounding rectangle of the contour
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(largestcontour)

cropped_img = img[y+3:y+h-3,x+3:x+w-3]
cv2.imshow('cropped', cropped_img)
cv2.waitkey(0)
```

Comment: You may read this [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to provide more information such as sample image and code you attempted to solve the problem, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

1. Convert image to HSV
2. Threshold image with colors in a certain range
3. Detect contours in the thresholded image
4. Filter contours using hierachy to only extract inner contours
5. Extract ROIs based on the bounding rectangles of the contours

If you are still completely stumped, view this example [code](https://gist.github.com/siphomateke/78cc10a5c0a978f9399098e92754c1ce)

Comment: Did you try it out? It is not as simple as you think it is..... It returns more bounding boxes than expected..

Comment: @JeruLuke Yes I did try it out and worked perfectly. (see my updated answer)

Comment: OK I did too. But did you count the number of contours it returns?

Comment: @JeruLuke Yes, it returns 1. See [this](https://gist.github.com/nextgensparx/78cc10a5c0a978f9399098e92754c1ce) example code

Comment: ok, but according to the image, the user sees that there are 19 bounding boxes. How will you identify that?

Comment: @JeruLuke Where does it say that there are 19 bounding boxes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139513/discussion-between-sipho-and-jeru-luke).